# Retrieve a value in a table-like custom object

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a table (imported from a csv file). I can do it with 2 lines but i guess I'm missing something and it could probably be done in only one line.

Here is the code:

```
$bar = $foo | where-Object  {$_.Myvalue -eq "network"  }
$bar.label
```

This is working actually. But I guess I can do that within a single line but I found out how.

Comment: PS3+: `$foo | ? Myvalue -eq "network" | select -expand label`

Comment: or `($foo | Where-Object { $_.Myvalue -eq "network" }).label`

Answer (score 4):

Try `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$foo | where-Object {$_.Myvalue -eq "network" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Label
```

Or `Foreach-Object`:

```
$foo | where-Object {$_.Myvalue -eq "network" } | Foreach-Object { $_.Label }
```

Comment: Which is exactly why he needs it. `$foo` is an object with a label-property which he wants the value from. Without expand he would receive a new object with only that property. With expand he will get the actual value of "label"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to retrieve the value:

```
$foo | where-Object {$_.Myvalue -eq "network" } | Select-Object -expand label
```

Answer (score 1):

`($foo | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.MyValue -eq "network" }).label` should work if you do not want to retain the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Example of solutions. Some have already been proposed.

```
$foo=import-csv "C:\temp\gogo.csv"

#possibility 0, with ultra short version of where and select
$foo | ? Myvalue -eq "network" | Select label

#possibility 1, with short version of where and select
$foo | Where Myvalue -eq "network" | Select label

#possibility 2, with property on list result
($foo | Where Myvalue -eq "network").label

#possibility 3, with where property
$foo.Where({$_.Myvalue -eq "network"}).label

#possibility 4, with if into foreach
$foo | %{ if ($_.Myvalue -eq "network") {$_.label}}

#possibility 5, with format table
$foo | Where Myvalue -eq "network" | Format-Table label
```